# Read data from linked SQL tables with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a question about reading data from my SQL-Server with two linked Tables:

The database tables with the relationships was created automatically via EF (with "Update-Database"...). My Class Structure is like this:

```cs
public class Item
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
   public List<Values> ValueList{ get; set; }
}

public class Values
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public decimal value { get; set; }
}
```

The auto generated DB-Model creates two tables (Item and Values) linked with a new column in the Values-Table (named ItemId). This is part of the auto generated DB-Model:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity("Values", b =>
  {
    b.Property<Guid>("Id")
      .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
      .HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier");
    b.Property<Guid?>("ItemId")
      .HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier");
    b.Property<decimal>("value")
      .HasPrecision(22, 4)
      .HasColumnType("decimal(22,4)");
    b.HasKey("Id");
    b.HasIndex("ItemId");
    b.ToTable("Values", (string)null);
  });

modelBuilder.Entity("Item", b =>
  {
    b.Property<Guid>("Id")
      .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
      .HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier");
    b.Property<string>("name")
      .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");
    b.HasKey("Id");
    b.ToTable("Item", (string)null);
  });

modelBuilder.Entity("Values", b =>
  {
    b.HasOne("Item", null)
      .WithMany("ValueList")
      .HasForeignKey("ItemId");
  });

modelBuilder.Entity("Item", b =>
  {
    b.Navigation("ValueList");
  });
```

Up to here everything is as expected. When I want to save an item object to the DB, I just pass the whole object:

```cs
var item1 = new Item(){...};

_dbContext.Set<Item>().Add(item1);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

And the EF store everything in the correct Tables. But if I try to read with this:

```cs
var data = (from e in _dbContext.Set<Item>()
           where e.name == "Pete" 
           select e).ToList();
```

I get an Item-Object but the `List<Values> ValuesList` prop is always empty... How do I get the whole data?

Comment: You may want to take a look at the official docs for [loading related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/)

Comment: This is what I was looking for.... I just didn't know what to look for. Thank you!